# Kion mi povas diri anstataŭ "Je via sano!"?

Tags: culture

Kiam oni levas glasojn, mi scias ke la kutima esperanta diraĵo estas "*Je via sano*". Sed, alemanaŭ en mia lando, oni ofte ankaŭ en tiu situacio honoras iun, ekzemple novgeedzoj aŭ naskiĝtagulo. Povas ankaŭ temi pri iu ĝoj-temo. Ekzemple ke iu ricevis bonan postenon aŭ akiris la kondukpermesilon. Ne devas rilati al persono, oni eĉ povas tosti pro bona vetero. Kion dirus esperantisto en tia kazo?

Answer (score 5):

Tio estas normala ofta okazaĵo ankaŭ en mia lando en la angla. Por Esperanto mi supozas ke tio dependas de la kulturoj de la specifaj parolantoj.

En mia sperto en festo parolante Esperanton ni diras «tosti je io», kaj tio povas esti io ajn, ne nur ies sano. Ekzemple iu povus proponi «ni tostu je la barbo de Zamenhof» kaj poste ĉiu samtempe diros «je la barbo de Zamenhof» dum ili tintas la glasojn.

Mi trovis ekzemplon de tia vortumo en [Marina de Sten Johansson](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/465080):

> Oni tostas je la sesdek jaroj de Arne, per senalkoholaj trinkaĵoj.

Kaj ankaŭ en [Skabio](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/548700) de la sama verkisto:

> Ŝi ankaŭ bonvenigis ĉiujn, transdonis salutojn de kelkaj forestantoj, kaj rakontis pri la bedaŭrindaj mortoj de Peter kaj Michael. Oni tostis je tiuj kaj je ĉiuj forestantoj.